# OR operating in the anydb-sql node module

Tags: node.js

I want to use or operation in my query having where clause with multiple filter.

I am using anydb-sql node module in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can use something like this

```
user
    .select(user.id)
    .from(user)
    .where(
      user.name.equals('boom').and(user.id.equals(1))
    ).or(
      user.name.equals('bang').and(user.id.equals(2))
    ).toQuery();
```